# Can a functional be linear independent to a function?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Define $f(x)$ as any real function in an inner product space, $f(x) = 0$ when $|x|>c, c \in \mathbb{R}$

and $g(f)$ is mapping between curve $f$ and real number.

$ f,g \in \mathbb{R}$

We could define the inner product as $ \langle h,g\rangle  = \int_\infty h(f(x))g(f(x)) dx $

$h(f(x))$ could be something as trivial as $h(f(x))=1\times f(x)$

And it is obvious that $h$ and $g$ could be linear dependent in some cases...

It is hard to image it in one's mind, since functionals and functions look like different beasts.

But does math told the math newbie that it is true?

Comment: What is demanded of an inner product?

Comment: Is $\langle f,g\rangle  = \int_\infty f(x)g(f(x)) dx$ well defined? I think that additional hypotheses are missing about $f$ and $g$... Which are the sets they belong to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

(Conjugate) symmetry is one of the properties demanded for an inner product:

$$<f,g> = \overline {<g,f>}$$

for real numbers, conjugate can be skipped as every real number is it's own conjugate:

$$<f,g> =  {<g,f>}$$

Anyway this leads to:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)g(f(x)) dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(x)f(g(x)) dx$$

Which is to be demanded for all pairs of functions belonging to some set of functions constituting your space. What space could that be?

Comment: Thanks. I do math for fun. Bananananch space and semi-inner-product I guess?